# MySQL Time vs epoch comparison

Tags: mysql, database, epoch

I am trying to implement logic that returns the "best" of three times.  My DB fields are:

```
FIRST_TIME - this is a long value in milliseconds from the epoch
SECOND_TIME - also a long value in milliseconds from the epoch
THIRD_TIME - this is an Time field, representing US/Eastern time, like 08:30:52
```

My logic should be:

1. If FIRST_TIME is populated, return that in HH:mm:ss converted to US/Eastern time
2. else if SECOND_TIME (converted to US/Eastern) is later than THIRD_TIME, return SECOND_TIME in US/Eastern time
3. else return THIRD_TIME

I can use FROM_UNIXTIME to get the first two fields in HH:mm:ss, but I am confused on how to convert that to the right time zone, and furthermore how to compare my fields and return the best value.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice, thank you Marc!  Now I can convert my epoch times into Time values using:

```
TIME(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(SUBSTRING(FIRST_TIME,1,10)),'GMT','US/Eastern'))
```

Now all that remains is how to use MySQL to sort out the logic for me.  I was able to do it with this:

```
(IF (FIRST_TIME IS NOT NULL,
    TIME(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(SUBSTRING(FIRST_TIME,1,10)),'GMT','US/Eastern')), 
IF(TIME(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(SUBSTRING(SECONT_TIME,1,10)),'GMT','US/Eastern')) > THIRD_TIME,
    TIME(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(SUBSTRING(SECOND_TIME,1,10)),'GMT','US/Eastern')),
THIRD_TIME))
) AS BEST_TIME,
```